# pcap C check if in monitor mode

Tags: c, pcap

I am capturing in C with libpcap on a device, that does not support to be set in monitor mode via pcap (pcap_can_set_rfmon returns -6). But i can set it in monitor mode with iw and iwconfig on command line, so I do that manually and then run the program.
I am also capturing on my Mac where I can set the network device to monitor mode with the pcap function pcap_set_rfmon.

I was wondering if there is a way with pcap to actually check if the device already is in monitor mode, just for error handling and convenience reasons. I didn't find an answer (either positive nor negative). So maybe someone here can answer this?

Answer (score 0):

> I am capturing in C with libpcap on a device, that does not support to be set in monitor mode via pcap (pcap_can_set_rfmon returns -6).

`pcap_can_set_rfmon()` returns -6?  That's `PCAP_ERROR_RFMON_NOTSUP`, which `pcap_can_set_rfmon()` isn't supposed to return; it's only supposed to return an error value if a problem occurs, it's supposed to return 0 if it thinks you can't set monitor mode and 1 if it thinks you can.  Do you mean that `pcap_set_rfmon()` returns -6?  And does `pcap_can_set_rfmon()`, which means "`pcap_set_rfmon()` should work"?

> But i can set it in monitor mode with iw and iwconfig on command line, so I do that manually and then run the program.

Do you run either of those commands as root, e.g. with `sudo`?

> I was wondering if there is a way with pcap to actually check if the device already is in monitor mode,

No.  The idea is that the result of `pcap_can_set_rfmon()` should correctly indicate whether `pcap_set_rfmon()` will succeed, and that programs should request monitor mode regardless of whether it's already on, just as they do with promiscuous mode.

Unfortunately, there are currently some issues with Linux - mostly a combination of the non-mac80211 mechanisms not working as well with libpcap as the mac80211 mechanisms (requiring more privileges, colliding with NetworkManager, etc.) and of the mac80211 mechanisms not being available to libpcap because libpcap currently requires the ever-changing-API libnl in order to use them (which may need to be fixed by directly using the netlink sockets).  This causes `pcap_set_rfmon()` not to work in cases where it should be able to work.

Comment: Ah sorry, I confound things a little... `pcap_can_set_rfmon()` returns 1, so monitor mode might be available. `pcap_set_rfmon()` succeeds, too, i.e. it returns 0. But then `pcap_activate()` returns -6 (PCAP_ERROR_RFMON_NOTSUP), when it already is in monitor mode as well as when it's not. And thats why I started setting the device in monitor mode with iw in the first place. So probably a library problem with Linux (using Ubuntu 10.10 Server)? An option to check if the device already is in monitor mode would just have been nice to notify myself if I forget to put the device to monitor mode.